# Forward/Reverse link possible with emacs/XML mode?

Tags: xml, emacs

I asked similar question about [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629046/forward-reverse-link-possible-with-emacs-html-mode), but I want to know if emacs XML mode has the feature.

- Is there 'M-x browse-url-of-file' equivalent in XML mode? I mean, is there any key that can pop up xml editor (XMLEditor or similar)?
- Is there any XML editing tool to enable the reverse link back to emacs XML mode?

#### ADDED

Based on slomojo's comment, I think if emacs' nXML mode can do whatever my XML editor (XMLEditor with Mac, XML Editor with PC)  can do, I don't need this forward/reverse link.

These are what I found useful with XMLEditor.

- collapsable node : I can collapse a whole/part of a tree if necessary.
- Grammar checker : If the XML has DTD, XML Editor checks if XML tree follows the DTD.
- Easy search and replace

There might be more, but those are what I need mostly.

Comment: There's good quality XML editing provided by nxml-mode. It would be good to know which features you need in an XML editor.

Answer (score 1):

1. nxml-mode has built in support for hiding, but by default it is set up for DocBook, you need to customize it for anything else. You can also customize outline-mode to recognize XML tags, or use hs-minor-mode to hide and show different levels of tags. The latter two can also be used with xml-mode.  [See here](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/NxmlModeForXHTML#toc4) for details on how to set it up (the instructions are for XHTML, but can be adapted for any XML dialect.
2. nxml-mode can check against RelaxNG schemas, so you need to convert your DTDs first. Use [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) to convert, and see the nxml manual if you want to set things up so that your files get automatically associated with this schema. Without a schema, it will warn you if the file is not valid XML which is useful in itself.
3. M-% is not easy?